# Plotting sine wave with delayed starting time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a sine wave with a delayed starting time.

For example,

- Sine wave frequency: 1Hz
- Total time: 2s
- 2 periods

I want the sine wave to start at `t=1s` so there is only one period in my plot.

My code so far is

```
a = 1
d = 5
phi = 0

f = 1                 # frequency
dt = 0.01             # timestep
fs = 1/dt             # sampling rate
T = 1/f               # period
Ttot = 2              # total
N = int(Ttot/dt)      # number of samples

t = np.linspace(0, Ttot, N)         # time channel

signal = a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t + phi)+d     # sine signal

plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.xlim(0, 2*T)
plt.xlabel('Time / s')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

So in the plot I want to have for `t<1s`, `signal=d=const` and for `t>1s`, `signal = one period of sine function`.

Any ideas? I have to build a field function for a boundary condition in CFD simulation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the delay of your sine, you have to modify this line

```
t = np.linspace(0, Ttot, N)
```

for this

```
t = np.linspace(1, Ttot, N)
```

This will provide your samples for the calculation of your signal, between the value of 1 and `Ttot` (which is 2 here).

Then you can add a horizontal line of value `d` between 0 and your delay like this

```
plt.hlines(d, 0, 1)
```

when you add a variable named `delay` for example, the whole code looks like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = 1
d = 5
phi = 0

f = 1                 # frequency
dt = 0.01             # timestep
fs = 1/dt             # sampling rate
T = 1/f               # period
Ttot = 2              # total
N = int(Ttot/dt)      # number of samples

delay = 1

t = np.linspace(delay, Ttot, N)        # time channel

signal = a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t + phi)+d     # sine signal


plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.hlines(d, 0, delay)
plt.xlim(0, 2*T)
plt.xlabel('Time / s')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

which gives this following plot

[image: plot]